# ListView with max number of items showing last items

Tags: android, listview

I'm developing an application with a chat and I want to show only the last 50 messages by default. I'm using a ListView with a custom ListAdapter and I have accomplished limit the number of messages doing this:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Math.min(mMessages.size(), mNumberMessagesToDisplay);
    }
```

My problem is that now the list shows the FIRST 50 messages instead of the last. I have not idea of how solve it. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: In `getView()` you need to handle that.

Comment: Make dummy arraylist ans add last 50 rows in it

Comment: Why don't you reverse the list using `Collections.reverse(aList);`

Comment: Whether you solved your issue?

Comment: Thanks to all! I'm actually using the response of Fabio and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an ArrayList of your messages and add the last message to top of the listView and delete the last message of the bottom:

```
listView.addHeaderView(yourView);
arrayListOfMesagges.add(message);

    if (arrayListOfMesagges.length>=50){
      listView.removeViewAt(arrayListOfMesagges.length);
      arrayListOfMesagges.remove(arrayListOfMesagges.length);
}
```

Thats all